# How to add hourly buckets on x axis labels on a histogram?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I want to plot hourly buckets on histogram, like `0-1`, `1-2`, `2-3` and so on.
What I have is simple `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` ... hours plotted on x axis. I need too change it to `0-1`, `1-2`, `2-3`.. hours an so on

[image]

would appreciate any kind of hint.

Comment: Search for "xticklabels", you just need to redefine your labels in the form "x--(x+1)"

Comment: This is not a histogram, it's a bar plot.

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a coding service. Please read the following documentation, then [edit], and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Always provide a [mre] with **code, data, errors, current & expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)** & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and show your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data and plot like these:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 24
x = list(range(N))
y = np.random.random(N)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (16, 6))

ax.bar(x, y)
ax.set_xticks(x)

plt.show()
```

[image]

then you can set x tick labels with the line:

```
ax.set_xticklabels([f'{x[i]}-{x[(i + 1)%N]}' for i in range(N)])
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, sorry I was really caught up and I didn't see this later. But I really appreciate this. It worked for me. Thank You!!